# How to store a single quote in sql variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, single-quotes

```
Declare @qt varchar(5)
Declare @xmlt xml
 set @qt = '''
```

I am unable to store a single quote in a variable, I need to concatenate before and after a column like below

```
update #TEMP_TABLE2
set XMLDatat =CONCAT(@qt,@xmlt,@qt)
```

So i have a single quote before and after the column

Comment: Have u tried `set @qt = ''''` ?

Comment: @Kumar Which MS SQl server version you are using

Comment: @YogeshSharma I have tried and single quote getting stored

Comment: @AlfaizAhmed I am using MS sql server 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
Declare @qt varchar(5)
Declare @xmlt xml
SET @qt = ''''
SET @xmlt ='Sample XML'

UPDATE #TEMP_TABLE2
SET XMLDatat = CONCAT(@qt,CAST(@xmlt AS VARCHAR(MAX)),@qt)
```

Thanks.